# DataFlow autoscaling workers not being created

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run the following beam pipeline in DataFlow and hoping for some help understanding how to optimise it to autoscale.

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    bq_query = f""""""
    
    query_results = ( p 
      | 'Query BQ' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(use_standard_sql=True, query=bq_query)
      #| 'Reshuffle' >> beam.Reshuffle()                  
    )
    
    rows = ( query_results
      | 'Parse Json Column' >> beam.ParDo(ParseJsonColumn())
      )
    
    output1 = ( rows 
      | 'Process1' >> beam.ParDo(Process1())
      | 'Api Call ' >> beam.ParDo(MakesApiCall())
      | 'Output1 Schema' >> beam.ParDo(Output1Schema())
      | 'Write Output1 To BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(Output1BQ_Table, schema=Output1Schema.get_schema(),
                                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
    )

    output2 = ( rows
      | 'Output2 Schema' >> beam.ParDo(Output2Schema())
      | 'Write Output2 To BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(Output2BQ_Table, schema=Output2Schema.get_schema(),
                                      write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                      create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
    )

    output3 = ( rows
      | 'Output3 Schema' >> beam.ParDo(Output3Schema())
      | 'Write Ooutput3 To BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(Output3BQ_Table, schema=Output3Schema.get_schema(),
                                      write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                      create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
    )
```

I am launching the pipeline locally using

```
python src/main.py \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--project my-project \
--region whatever-region \
--temp_location gs://my-bucket/tmp \
--staging_location gs://my-bucket/staging \
--setup_file src/setup.py \
--max-workers=50
```

When it runs in DataFlow it is really slow, processing only 1 row from the BigQuery result at a time.
The bigquery results do contain a rather large string column containing json which is parsed in the 'Parse Json Column' step.
I was hoping this step would scale up, along with the step 'Api Call'.
DataFlow does appear to want to autoscale, it reports that Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 221 but the current workers always stays at 1.
Also I wonder why it is not respecting the --max-workers argument of 50 when I launch the job?

Any help to understand how best to structure the pipeline to achieve this autoscaling would be much appreciated.

TIA

**** Update
launching with `--dataflow_service_options=enable_prime` appears to have had an affect.
Now it looks to have tried scaling workers to 10 but only managed to get 8, says `This could be a quota issue`
Again it keeps says its raising the workers even above the `--max-workers=50` but it never goes above 8.

Comment: Have you checked https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshoot-autoscaling#scaling-stops?